# java.lang.AbstractMethodError for Java 8 application running on Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to upgrade a Spring application to Java 8. It works perfectly in Java 6, but gives a run time error in the newer version of Java. I am trying to deploy it on Tomcat 9.

I have the following DAO class:

```java
Map inParams = new HashMap(8);
inParams.put("p_aId", aId);
inParams.put("p_bId", bId);
inParams.put("p_cid", cId);         

Map result = execute(inParams);
```

Upon calling the execute, it calls HashMap.java and throws this error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:379)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:114)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:532)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:923)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:985)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:117)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.wrappers.AbstractMethodWrapper.internalInvoke(AbstractMethodWrapper.java:164)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.wrappers.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:287)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.JaxRsRestlet.invokeMethod(JaxRsRestlet.java:708)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.JaxRsRestlet.handle(JaxRsRestlet.java:452)
    at org.restlet.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.Filter.handle(Filter.java:195)
    at org.restlet.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.Filter.handle(Filter.java:195)
    at org.restlet.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.Filter.handle(Filter.java:195)
    at org.restlet.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at com.noelios.restlet.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:130)
    at org.restlet.Filter.handle(Filter.java:195)    
    at org.restlet.Filter.handle(Filter.java:195)
    at org.restlet.Router.handle(Router.java:502)
    at org.restlet.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.Filter.handle(Filter.java:195)
    at com.noelios.restlet.ChainHelper.handle(ChainHelper.java:124)
    at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:888)
    at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:331)
    at com.noelios.restlet.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:68)
    at com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:147)
    at com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:790)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748
```

The same code works fine in Java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AbstractMethodError` and its stacktrace suggests that `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid` tries to call [`Connection.isValid`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)) on your actual database connection, but the version of the JDBC driver you're using doesn't implement this method. This means that you're using a JDBC 3.0 (Java 1.4/Java 5) or earlier JDBC driver, or at least one that doesn't implement methods introduced in JDBC 4.0 (Java 6).

In other words, you need to upgrade your JDBC driver to a version that does implement `Connection.isValid` and thus is JDBC 4.0 compliant (preferably even JDBC 4.2 (Java 8)), or replace your driver by a different one. Alternatively, you can configure DBCP to validate a connection using a query (the `validationQuery` [config option of DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html)), but as using an old JDBC driver would likely make you run into other problems as well, I would instead recommend upgrading/replacing your JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Updating the jdbc driver resolved the issue.